# CreateJS Collision Detection

Tags: javascript, createjs

I am having a problem with setting up collision detection. I've followed a few posts from this forum and the web, but can't seem to get it to work. I am trying to use the square bounding box approach, located in a function.

Square is the shape that moves around the canvas with user input, and impactSquare is the stationary shape that I am trying to test the impact with.  I can't seem to figure out what part is causing it not to work.

```
//square bounding box
if (impactSquare.x < square.x + square.width &&
    impactSquare.x + impactSquare.width > square.x &&
    impactSquare.y < square.y + square.height &&
    impactSquare.height + impactSquare.y > square.y) {
    // collision detected!
    //square.graphics.beginFill("#F4F4F4");
    console.log("Collision Detected");
} else {
    // no collision
    //square.graphics.beginFill("#FF0000");
    console.log("No Collision"); 
}
//stage.update();
```

Thank you for an help you can provide!

Comment: Could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ (and/or) any error messages that come up in the console? From just that code I do not see the problem with the collision. How often is this code called?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't get any errors =)  If I add a Ticker call, it just keeps writing "No Impact" over and over, even when there should be a collision.  I am calling the function detectCollision(); in my init(); function.

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with this collision function (assuming everything else is correct), look at this Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AniHouse/zxe2a5aL/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably having issues because you're trying the hitTest, which is pixel-perfect.

Here, use this: https://github.com/olsn/Collision-Detection-for-EaselJS works like a charm.

If the the intersection is empty, that's because there was no collision.

```
if (intersection !== null) {
   //  hit
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: This is *bounding box collision detection*, which is efficient and used often. I have done collision detection like this countless times. I don't see why you think there is something wrong with it.

Comment: All of my code can be found here: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/OutdoorPhoto/t459tac6/19/)

Comment: Changed my shapes to bitmaps/jpg and the Collision-Detection-for-EaselJS works great!  It doesn't work with shapes though, so you have to use bitmaps.